# How to show that following function is analytic in domain |z|<1 and and domain |z|>1

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Consider the following problem:

> Show that $f(z)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}[ z^{2^{n+1}}/ (1-z^{2^{n+1}})] $ is analytic in domain |z|<1 and domain |z|>1 .

So, I thought of trying to find it's radius of convergence and seeing if i can deduce anything from it.

But, finding the radius of convergence is itself a herculian  task(to me atleast ) for this question and so I think there must be some alternative approaches for this question but could not think of any.

Can you please tell me which results should I use.

No need to fully solve the question , just outlines will be sufficient.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a power series, so radius of convergence is not even defined.

Let $|z| \leq r$ where $r <1$. Then $|\frac {z^{2^{n+1}}} {1-z^{2^{n+1}}}|\leq \frac {r^{2^{n+1}}} {1-r }$. Hence the series converges uniformly on compact subsets of the open unit disk. This makes $f$ analytic in this disk.

I will leave the case $|z|>1$ to you. Just divide numerator and denominator by $z^{2^{n+1}}$.